# Nodejs: How can I reuse Requested data from one module to another modules?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, node-modules

**What I need to do:**
I want to get First_Name from user.js which the user selected into identity.js file to store it in another MySQL table. It will be also good that after using it, will goes/empty to prevent a memory leak. Thankful for any help.

**What I have:**

```
********server/app.js*********
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const addUser = require('./routes/user');
const identity = require('./routes/identity');
const port = 8080;
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

// routes for the app
app.post('/add', addUser);
app.use('/identity', identity);

// set the app to listen on the port
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});


*******user.js******
module.exports = {
    addUser: (req, res) => {

        let First_Name = req.body.First_Name;
        let Last_Name = req.body.Last_Name;

        let query = "INSERT INTO `user` (First_Name, Last_Name) VALUES ('" +
                    First_Name + "', '" + Last_Name + "')";
        db.query(query, (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
              return res.status(500).send(err);
              }
           res.send('Success');
           console.log('User Created successfully !');
        });            
    }
};

******identity.js*********
const identity = express.Router();

//Store the selected option from Radiobutton in MySQL into another table
identity.post('/', (req, res) => {

    let selection = req.body.selectedOption;
    //***here I want to get First_Name which user selected in user.js***
    //const query = "INSERT INTO `document` (First_Name , selection ) VALUES ('" + First_Name + "','" + selection + "')";
    db.query(query, (err, _result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.send('Success');
        console.log('stored successfully !');
    });
});
module.exports = identity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract your database post into its own function and give it an interface `(query) => Promise`. At the moment you are writing to the database and to a response in one place.

Make the new database function return a Promise that it will resolve or reject based on the outcome of posting to the database.

Then in the post handler, call the function and respond to the web request based on the Promise outcome.

Export the database function. Import it from the user module, and use it there.

Make your functions do one thing only and give them interfaces that expose that. Your database post takes the query to post and returns a statement about the outcome.

Your handler takes a request, calls functions that do things, and responds based on the outcomes. Both the handlers will have that shape once you move that db function out.

It is controller / service separation of concerns.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I'm new to it so unable to understand much. Can you tell me more or give links that have some this type of practice. So that I can relate it.